# How to Convert String to Date Format in MongoDB Compass Database Collection

Tags: python, string, mongodb, date, types

I have tried converting string to date as I wanted to filter out my data wrt to date period.
This Image shows my Collection and Query which i used to filter my data as it was showing error so i wanted to change the string to date for all records or created_at field.

[Date Conversion Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIbDQ.png)

[MongoDB Compass][2]

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Comment: Compass shows `"created_at"` as a string.  You'll have a better experience if your dates are BSON dates.